# Mongoose: Not able to add one item in Mongoose array SchemaType. Although more than one could be added

Tags: arrays, node.js, forms, express, mongoose

Below is my Schema

```
var makerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    materials:[
        {
            type: String,
            required:[true, "Material is a required field"],
            trim:true,
            lowercase:true,
            enum:{
                values:['wood','metal','plastic','glass','concrete','other'], 
                message: 'Please choose from the given options only!'
            }
        }
    ]
},{
    timestamps:true
})

var Maker = mongoose.model('Maker', makerSchema);
```

Below is my route

```
router.post('/maker', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var maker = new Maker(req.body);
        await maker.save();
        res.status(200).send();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
            let errors = {};

            Object.keys(error.errors).forEach((key) => {
              errors[key] = error.errors[key].message;
            });

            return res.status(400).send(errors);
          }
          res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})
```

Below is my form in which I can select multiple items by holding Ctrl and clicking options.

```
<form action="/maker" method="POST">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="materials" name="materials">
       <option>Wood</option>
       <option>Metal</option>
       <option>Glass</option>
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But in case I select single option I get the following error, although works fine for multiplele options:

```
{"materials.0":"Please choose from the given options only!"}
```

How do I resolve this error and allow users to choose not only multiple but single options too?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when selecting ONE material only you will get the "wrong" datatype for `maker.materials`, a `String`.
When selecting multiple materials you will receive a `Array<String>` in your router.

So I would check the datatype of `materials`in the router before saving the `Maker`. And convert it to `Array` if it is not one already.